# Angular ng-animate change attribute

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I have a div that holds ng-views(partials)

```
<div ng-view class="animate-container" data-ng-animate="myAnimation"></div>
```

I  change my myAnimation in controller from

```
$scope.myAnimation = { enter: 'forth-enter', leave: 'forth-leave' };
```

to

```
$scope.myAnimation = { enter: 'back-enter', leave: 'back-leave' };
```

I also print {{myAnimation}} in view so that I can see the change.

Problem is that the change is made but the forth animation is still triggered..
It does not update the animation. I've set up some directive to watch the animations trigger start and setup, so I know it works, I've also tried to do it the other way around instead of doing from forth->back i do back->forth and I get the same problem, it works but it wont change.

really appreciate any help with this, I've picked this technique up on YearOfMoo site
http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html

"Skip Specific Animations by changing the $scope"

Comment: Add a punklr sample, than we can help you better...

Comment: It could just be a scoping issue. Perhaps set your animation value inside of {{$root.animation}} and use $rootScope to read/write the animation value.

Comment: Problem was a small fix in the angular.js. Updated to the latest version on git not angularjs.com and got it to working. Thanks to Mathias, really great support from Angular team i would never had found it myself.